# Alfresco 4.0d Custom Aspect Search

Tags: alfresco-share

I'm currently developing a custom search in Alfresco for some custom aspects that I've created . Can you direct me to the correct xml file which I need to edit to add my custom aspects in the search? I have researched numerous posts on the web but I couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 1):

Explain better,
do you mean the default advanced search in Alfresco Explorer?
In that case, you should search for a file named web-client-config-custom.xml.sample inside:

```
/Alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension
```

or

```
/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/extension
```

Then rename the file removing the sample extension, to have web-client-config-custom.xml and copy the file inside the first path above (the "shared" one, not the webapps/alfresco one);
Then, inside, search for a tag named "config evaluator" Advanced Search, it should be something like this:

```
     <!-- Example of configuring advanced search -->
   <!--
   <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Advanced Search">
      <advanced-search>
         <content-types>
         </content-types>
         <custom-properties>
            <meta-data aspect="app:simpleworkflow" property="app:approveStep" />
         </custom-properties>
      </advanced-search>
   </config>
   -->
```

There, you can add your custom aspects that you created in your customModel.xml file.
To extend the custom advanced search capabilities, you could add some custom content type search or properties that are not part of the aspects, like this:

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Advanced Search">
    <advanced-search>
        <content-types>
            <type name="myNamespace:customType" />
        </content-types>
        <custom-properties>
            <meta-data type="myNamespace:customType" property="myNamespace:customTypeProperty" />
            <meta-data aspect="myNamespace:customAspect" property="myNamespace:customAspectProperty" />
        </custom-properties>
    </advanced-search>
</config>
```

hope it helps..

Comment: I had already edited that file, but I just have created an aspect not a type in my environment. It shows the custom aspects in alfresco share and can add them and save data in the fields. But it seems I cannot add the custom search for them.

Comment: Just a second, are you using Share instead of Alfresco Explorer? In that case, the files to modify are different. You have to edit **share-config-custom.xml**, like [this](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Share_Advanced_Search). You have to extend the
`<config evaluator="model-type" condition="cm:content">` and add the aspect you want to be included in the advanced form search. Remember that you have to use the property unique name inside your aspect instead that the aspect name itself. If you still don't manage to accomplish what you need i'll post an example maybe. Hope it helps.